# How to bind checkbox to model binder that were created dynamically

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

I added checkbox dynamically in the view with `PropertiesList` select box. When submiting the form it posted the checkbox data but in controller `Properties` in null that presented in below image.

Browser header:
[image: browser header]

Debugging mode:
[image: debugging mode]

Model:

```
public class ModelView
{
    [HiddenInput]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> PropertiesList { get; set; }
    public List<PropertyModels> Properties { get; set; }
}
public class PropertyModels
{
    public int PropertyID { get; set; }
    public string PropertyIcon { get; set; }
    public int PropertyType { get; set; }
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label>Properties</label>
<select id="PropertiesList" class="form-control" placeholder="Add ...">
   @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Properties.Count(); i++)
     {
       <option value="@Model.Properties[i].PropertyID" data-value="@Model.Properties[i].IsSelected" data-icon="@Model.Properties[i].PropertyIcon">@Model.Properties[i].PropertyName</option>
     }
 </select>
 </div>
 <div>
 <dl class="dl-horizontal"></dl>
 </div>
```

JQuery:

```
    $("#PropertiesList").on("change", function (e) {
        var id = $(this).val();
        var icon = $('#PropertiesList option:selected').attr('data-icon');
        var name = $('#PropertiesList option:selected').text();


        var dt = "<dt><span class='" + icon + "'></span> <span>" + name + "</span></dt>";
        var value = ($('#PropertiesList option:selected').attr('data-value') === "True");
        var dd = "<dd><input id='Properties_" + id + "__IsSelected' name='Properties[" + id + "].IsSelected' type='checkbox' class='minimal' value='false'> \
                     <input name='Properties[" + id + "].IsSelected' type='hidden'></dd>";
        }

        $('.dl-horizontal').append(dt + dd);
    });
```

Conrtoller:

```
    public virtual ActionResult EditView(int Id)
    {
        List<PropertyModels> PropertyItems = new List<PropertyModels>();

        using (var context = new DB())
        {
            var properties = context.Property
            .Where(prpinfo => prpinfo.Status == true)
            .Select(prpinfo => new
            {
                prp_id = prpinfo.PropertyID,
                prp_name = prpinfo.PropertyName
                prp_icon = prpinfo.PropertyIcon,
            });

            foreach (var prp in properties)
            {
                PropertyModels prop = new PropertyModels();
                prop.PropertyID = prp.prp_id;
                prop.PropertyName = prp.prp_name.FirstOrDefault().prp_name;
                prop.PropertyIcon = prp.prp_icon;
                prop.IsSelected = false;
                PropertyItems.Add(prop);
            }
            AddPlanModelView EPW = new AddPlanModelView()
            {
                Properties = PropertyItems
            };
            return View(EPW);
        }

    }
    [HttpPost]
    public virtual ActionResult EditView(ModelView MW)
    {
        if (TryUpdateModel(Plan, includeProperties: new[] { "PlanId","Title","Properties" }))
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                using (var context = new DB())
                {

                    var selected_property = context.ModelProperty.Where(d => d.ID == MW.Id)
                            .Select(prpinfo => new
                            {
                                prp_id = prpinfo.PropertyID,
                                prp_val = prpinfo.PropertyValueID
                            }).ToList();
                    IList<ModelProperty> modelprps = new List<ModelProperty>();
                    foreach (var cc in ModelView .Properties)
                    {
                        var match = selected_property.Where(c => c.prp_id == cc.PropertyID).Count();
                        if (match == 0)
                        {

                                modelprps.Add(new ModelProperty() { ModelID = Plan.PlanId, PropertyID = cc.PropertyID, Value = cc.IsSelected.ToString() });
                        }
                    }
                    context.ModelProperty.AddRange(modelprps);

                        }
                    }
                    context.SaveChanges();
                    return Json(new { success = true });
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return Json(new { success = false });
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(new { success = false });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just give `Properties` as name.

Comment: @Berkay  i did it but it's null.

Comment: Collection indexers need to start a zero and be consecutive. And suggest you refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019793/submit-same-partial-view-called-multiple-times-data-to-controller/28081308#28081308)